# Почему ставится запятая перед первым тире при обособлении вводной конструкции?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вставная-конструкция

*Глядя на него, Мечику невольно захотелось всё рассказать самому, **– в сущности, он любил такие вещи,** – но ему казалось, что все смотрят на него с удивлением и выйдет очень неловко (Фурманов. Разгром).*

Сравнить: *Издалека  –  **должно быть**, из железнодорожных мастерских – тоже откликнулись низкие гудки.*

Спасибо.

Comment: Это «симметрия» знаков.

Comment: Смотря как вы понимаете эту симметрию.  Ведь вставка относится к первой части предложения (до союза НО).

Comment: А что, может ко второй относится или к двум сразу? Нет.

Comment: Содержание вставки явно относится к первой части, и это нужно изобразить графически отсутствием запятой и паузы соответственно.  Симметричная реплика  – это общее замечание, отнесенное ко всему предложению

Comment: Это да, только вот пауза не может отсутствовать в связи с тире. Что-то вы забыли про симметрию, о которой сказано у Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123

Comment: Ничего у него там не сказано по принципу: догадайся, мол, сам, если ты такой умный. А если нет, но и рассказывать бесполезно.  И старайтесь не забывать  о том, что мы не знаки обычно ставим, а устную речь "нотами" записываем.

Comment: Там нет ничего скрытого, просто симметрия, и всё. Это тот случай, когда не нужно искать причины (потому что их нет).

Comment: Ладно, дискуссию закрываем, о то весь вопрос удалят вместе с комментариями.  Договорим еще...  А причину надо искать всегда.